# Почему не приходит сообщение на почту?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```js
$('#sendMail').on('click', function() {
  let name = $('#name').val().trim();
  let face = $('#face').val().trim();
  let personal_account = $('#personal_account').val().trim();
  let addres = $('#addres').val().trim();
  let email = $('#email').val().trim();
  let phone = $('#phone').val().trim();
  let text = $('#text').val().trim();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'mail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      "name": name,
      "face": face,
      "personal_account": personal_account,
      "addres": addres,
      "email": email,
      "phone": phone,
      "text": text,
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#sendMail').prop('disabled', true);
    },
    success: function() {
      $('#sendMail').prop('disabled', false);
      alert("Успешно отправили заявку")
    }
  });
});
```

```css
<?php $name=$_POST['name'];
$face=$_POST['face'];
$personal_account=$_POST['personal_account'];
$addres=$_POST['addres'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$text=$_POST['text'];
$subject="=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode("Сообщение с сайта")."?=";
$headers="From: $email\r\nReply-to: $email" $success=mail("denis_sokolov69@mail.ru", $subject. $text, $headers);
echo $success;
?>
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="mail.php">
  <div class="feedback-form">
    <div class="feedback-form__name">
      <div class="feedback-form__title">Наименование организации / ФИО.*</div>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Наименование организации / ФИО.*" class="form-input" required>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-form__face">
      <div class="feedback-form__title">Контактное лицо</div>
      <input type="text" name="face" id="face" placeholder="Контактное лицо" class="form-input">
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-form__personal-account">
      <div class="feedback-form__title">Лицевой счет*</div>
      <input type="text" name="personal_account" id="personal_account" placeholder="Лицевой счет*" class="form-input" required>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-form__addres">
      <div class="feedback-form__title">Адрес*</div>
      <input type="text" name="addres" id="addres" placeholder="Адрес*" class="form-input" required>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-form__email">
      <div class="feedback-form__title">E-mail*</div>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail*" class="form-input" required>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-form__phone">
      <div class="feedback-form__title">Контактный телефон*</div>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Контактный телефон*" class="form-input" id="phone" value="999 999 99 99" required>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-form__text">
      <div class="feedback-form__title">Текст сообщения*</div>
      <textarea type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Текст сообщения*" class="form-input text" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-form__fail">
      <div class="feedback-form__title file">Прикрепить к приложению файл</div>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" />
      <label for="file" class="input-file">Выбрать файл</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="send" id="sendMail">Отправить сообщение</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в строке `$headers="From: $email\r\nReply-to: $email" $success=mail("denis_sokolov69@mail.ru", $subject. $text, $headers);` что-то напутано.

```
//  вашем коде пропущена точка с запятой в самом конце
$headers="From: $email\r\nReply-to: $email";

// в вашем коде идет точка после $subject
$success=mail("denis_sokolov69@mail.ru", $subject, $text, $headers);
```

И в целом, не мешало бы позаботиться о безопасности немного, потому что вам на почту по идее можно как минимум скрипт отправить.